# hibernate @OneToOne mapping with Principal REST

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, rest

**SOLUTION:** I solved it, here is the new RestUser.java if it can help anyone in the future

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rate", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity rate(@RequestBody Rating rating, Principal principal){

    User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
    Rating ratingAVG = ratingService.findOne(user.getId());
    ratingAVG.setFood(rating.getFood());
    ratingAVG.setService(rating.getService());
    user.setRating(ratingAVG);
    ratingAVG.setUser(user);
    userService.save(user);

    return new ResponseEntity("Rated!", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**QUESTION**

I've an issue while inserting/updating object that have a foreigner key. I have a table called Rating that looks like this. I want to add a unique Rating object that take the current user_id with `principal.getName()`. I'm using Advanced REST client to test it and am already logged in

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|                     Rating                     |
+------------------------------------------------+
| id |    food     |    service     |   user_id  |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+
|  1 |     5       |        5       |      1     |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+
```

User.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="Id", nullable=false, updatable=false)
private long id;

private String username;
private String password;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
@JoinColumn(name="user_id", unique=true)
private Rating rating;
```

Rating.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private int food;
private int service;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonIgnore
private User user;
```

RatingServiceimpl.java

```
@Service
public class RatingServiceImpl implements RatingService {

    @Autowired
    private RatingRepository ratingRepository;

    @Override
    public Rating save(Rating rating) {
        return ratingRepository.save(rating);
    }

}
```

UserRest.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserRest {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    RatingService ratingService;


    @RequestMapping(value="/rate", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity rate(@RequestBody Rating rating, Principal principal){

        User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
        user.setRating(rating);
        rating.setUser(user);
        userService.save(user);

        return new ResponseEntity("Rated!", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

This is what I get, it adds a new object while i just want it to update the existent one.

[MySQL Browser Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBiJP.jpg)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are saving the rating with our setting the user. I do not see any '@Transaction' annotations so I assume your transactions are inside the 'RatingRepository' meaning that you transaction will be committed before you set the rating to the user.

Try setting the user to the rating before calling save.

Comment: Thanks ! Now it adds a new object that takes the user_id but still doesn't replace the existent one. Any idea ?

I updated the UserRest.java and the image.